# Accurate interval timer inside rendering loop linux

Tags: linux, timer

What is the best way to do the following in Linux

```
while(continue)
    {
    render(); //this function will take a large fraction of the framerate
    wait();   //Wait until the full frame period has expired.
    }
```

On windows, waitable timers seems to work pretty well (within 1 ms). One way of proceeding is to use a separate thread that just sleeps and triggers a sychronization mechanism. However I do not know how much overhead there are in this.

Note: Accuracy is more important than high frequency: A timer with frequency 1.000 kHz is preffered over a timer with 1 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for an answer in the C language:

I don't remember the precision, but I recall I used to use the setitimer() function when I needed good precision.

Here's an example of how to use it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1602/chap7rt-89.html

Comment: What happens if this is already in use by a library running a loop in a separate thread?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Perhaps you could also have a look at a function called timer_create() which seems to be a more thread-aware. I don't know about its accuracy though.. :/

Perhaps see this other question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399802/posix-timer-runs-at-twice-the-expected-frequency